# Как убрать верхний отступ при header

Tags: html, css, html5, header, margin

[image: Не получаеться убрать отступ сверху]

Использовал margin и padding на ноль в body,html,header , не помогло

Comment: Отредактируйте пожалуйста свой вопрос и приложите html код

Answer (score 0):

У элемента `ul` по-умолчанию есть `margin: 1rem 0`. Просто уберите его

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не убирать margin и padding скачай и подключи reset.min.css